# Group policy preferences stopped working on vista sp2

Tags: windows-vista, group-policy

After I installed service pack 2 on one of our Vista (amd64) workstations the group policy preferences stopped applying. The preferences are still working on our xp sp3 and vista sp1 workstations.

This is happening in a pure Windows 2003 domain without any Windows 2008 servers.

I have seen this: http://blog.mpecsinc.ca/2009/05/vista-service-pack-2-not-applying-group.html but that can't be the way to install the client right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the problems seem to be todo with a slipstreamed SP2 install, but it's probably worth trying the technique outlined in this post:

http://forums.techarena.in/windows-vista-network/1176309.htm#post4430880

Comment: Yes. that is the same technique that was descirbed in the link in my original post. The problematic workstation is NOT a slipstreamed, but upgraded machine tho.

It seems that the answer to my question is yes then?

Answer (score 0):

I tested the solution in my original question and it clearly works. I guess I'll wait for an update to fix the problem before I deploy Vista sp2 here.